# Equivalency and memory space

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, we know that when you make changes to a StringBuilder object, unlike in String, it doesn't create a new object and copy all the new values from the old object, but changes it on the spot. 
Is there anything like that for int (integers), anything equivalent that doesn't create new object but just modifies the same object?

Comment: But an `int` is not an object to begin with. Are you aware of the difference between value types and reference types, and the implications?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look to [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and more generally all `Atomic` types from java default packages. Its supposed to be used primarily for concurrency purposes as all of the methods are synchronized but it should fit your usecase!

You can instanciate it like this :

```
AtomicInteger myInt = new AtomicInteger(8);
int myIntVal = myInt.get();
// increment it :
myInt.incrementAndGet(6);
// will output 6 + 8 = 14
int myNewIntVal = myInt.get();

myInt.set(16);
// new value is now of 16;
```